# Simulate Mouse Movement

Tags: javascript

Consider this scenario. A user moves their mouse inside a window. I have the windows dimensions and the mouse coordinates. For example:

```
let userInput = {
    window: {
        height: 822,
        width: 1440
    },
    mouse: {
        x: 1068,
        x_pct: "74.167",
        y: 1,
        y_pct: "0.111"
    }
}
```

And in a container, inside another window.
I would like to simulate the mouse movement and place an element such as a `div` in a position similar to the mouse position from the userInput.

A plain explanation would be, if the users mouse is in the top left of the window, place the element in the top left of the container.

I may be overthiking but i feel that the container width and height must be considered relative to the windows dimensions in order to place the element accurately in the window. So i can not just place the object in the same position as the userInput provides such as:

```
element.style.left = userInput.mouse.x + "px";
element.style.top = userInput.mouse.y + "px";
```

I feel i need to come up with a formular or algorithm to accomplish this. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This simple snippet could help you.

```
const myNewWindow = window.open("", "", "left=,top=10,width=320,height=320")
myNewWindow.document.write("<div id='target' style='position:absolute; background:red;'>Hello world!</div>")

document.addEventListener("mousemove", (e)=>{
    const mainW = window.innerWidth;
    const mainH = window.innerHeight;
    const popW = myNewWindow.innerWidth;
    const popH = myNewWindow.innerHeight;

    myNewWindow.document.getElementById("target").style.top = e.clientY / mainH * popH;
    myNewWindow.document.getElementById("target").style.left = e.clientX / mainW * popW;
});
```

With working example here: https://jsfiddle.net/nogare/1tejzmux/
Notice you need to enable pop-up windows.

Comment: Yes, it does help although reverse is the case. I want to listen for the mouse input from the bigger window (in this case, the popup window) and display on the smaller window. Does the same formula still apply?

Comment: Just swap `e.clientY / mainH * popH` to `e.clientY / popH * mainH` and `e.clientX / mainW * popW` to `e.clientX / popW * mainW`.

Comment: Also, there is an offset to my element. It does not take the full screen.

Comment: I suppose you mean ```e.clientY * mainH / popH``` and ```e.clientX* mainW / popW``` respectively.

Comment: I think i'm so close to getting it but now i just have to figure out how to factor in the offset change in the formula. 
Basically, the container (popup) where the co-ordinate output is displayed is centered in the page.
If you like, i can show you the project.

Comment: just add `position: relative` to container, it will make everything with `position: absolute` have default offset.

Comment: Please check out this pen 
https://codepen.io/chromesque/pen/ExRjqyw?editors=0010

Comment: dont forget to add "px" after posX and posY value: `posY+"px"`

Comment: Yes, i did forget indeed. I have made changes the code and now the cursor moves. But you'll notice the cursor is not inline with the frame. I want the cursor to be in the same position inside the frame as the mouse position in the popup. The popup width and height is the same as the frame width and height.